# Can't create AdSense account due to address verification issues

Tags: android, admob, adsense

While registering my first AdMob account, which requires the existing AdSense account, I've encountered one odd issue. To create AdSense account I need to enter my address. So, I open up Google Maps, search for my home ([here it is](https://www.google.ru/maps/place/ul.+Lva+Tolstogo,+10,+Tolyatti,+Samarskaya+oblast',+445004/@53.539312,49.396472,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4168789245c41fa3:0x708c95745283a5c6)) and copy-paste the address and postal code into the provided form, like so:
[image]
The last line contains my postal code. Whenever I click the 'Continue' button, the postal code field becomes red and the following error arises:

> This postal code does not appear to match the rest of this address.

I've tried all possible ways to write down my address afterwards - I've written it in English, in Russian, In Russian with latin letters. I could try to write it in German, though it doesn't make much sense.
Did anybody encounter the same issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about account setup(unrelated to programming). You should probably avoid posting your address on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after some trial and error I've found the way to register the AdSense account.

The postal codes in Russia are 6-digit long. First three digits are for federal subject (you can call it a region, if you like), other three dedicated to code some amount of houses in this area.

My region is 'Samarskaya Oblast'', which has the code of 443. AFAIK this region also has some other codes (it's common in Russia for huge regions, like Moscow Region, Saint Petersburg Region and some others), like 444, 445 and some others.

So, the city I live in (Tolyatti) has one of these additional Samara codes - 445. The building I live in has the following postal code: 445004. Here comes the strange part. For some reason AdSense thinks that postal codes starting from '445' can't be located in the Samara Region! I've changed the postal code to '443004' (which is clearly wrong), and it let me through.

Seems like there is an issue with AdSense itself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too. I needed to type a Postal code for Taganrog, Russia, which is 347900 (base city postal code, not a single post office) but it wasn't to be work for Google.
After reading this post I started to try different Postal Codes where first triplet less by 1, i.e.:

```
347 - 1 = 346000,
347 - 2 = 345000, 
347 - 3 = 344000   <- And this worked for me! :D
```

Comment: У меня такое не проходит, индекс 125459 (Москва), есть что кроме перебора?